# Return Oracle Row into Function/Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbeaver

I need to convert the following query into a function/procedure that returns the same.
 Here goes the query

```
SELECT ((SELECT count(*) FROM persona WHERE DTYPE = 'Vendedor' AND ACTIVO = 1) * (SELECT count(*) FROM TIPO_DOCUMENTO WHERE ENTIDAD = 'Vendedor' AND ACTIVO = 1) +
(SELECT count(*) FROM persona WHERE DTYPE = 'Peoneta' AND ACTIVO = 1) * (SELECT count(*) FROM TIPO_DOCUMENTO WHERE ENTIDAD = 'Peoneta' AND ACTIVO = 1)
+
(SELECT count(*) FROM VEHICULO WHERE ACTIVO = 1) * (SELECT count(*) FROM TIPO_DOCUMENTO WHERE ENTIDAD = 'Vehiculo' AND ACTIVO = 1 )) AS total, 
--Vigentes
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOC_PERS WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA >  SYSDATE +30  AND ACTIVO = 1) +
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOC_VEH WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA > SYSDATE +30 AND ACTIVO = 1))AS Vigentes,
--PorVencer
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOC_PERS WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA < SYSDATE +30 AND FECHA_VIGENCIA > SYSDATE + 15  AND ACTIVO = 1) +
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOC_VEH WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA < SYSDATE +30 AND FECHA_VIGENCIA > SYSDATE +15 AND ACTIVO = 1)) AS PorVencer,
--Criticos
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOC_PERS WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA < SYSDATE +15 AND FECHA_VIGENCIA > SYSDATE  AND ACTIVO = 1) +
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DOC_VEH WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA < SYSDATE +15 AND FECHA_VIGENCIA > SYSDATE AND ACTIVO = 1)) AS Criticos
FROM DUAL;
```

I know how to order it by putting every select into a variable, but i dont know how to return a row from there.

Im using dbveaver to edit this.

Comment: That's a lot of counts, but - unfortunately - I don't understand the question **at all**. Could you simplify it and describe the problem once again? You know, "I have *this* and what to do *this* to get *that*" - with examples, of course?

Comment: Editted, what i want is to make that long query into a function or procedure that returns the same values

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION RETURN NUMBER AS 
CNT1 NUMBER;
CNT2 NUMBER;
TOTAL NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO CNT1 FROM persona WHERE DTYPE = 'Vendedor' AND ACTIVO = 1 ... etc.;
  SELECT count(*) INTO CNT2 FROM persona WHERE DTYPE = 'Peoneta' AND ACTIVO = 1 ... etc.;
 TOTAL := CNT1 + CNT2 ....; etc
END TEST_FUNCTION;
```

Not 100% sure why you would want to do that though. If you want to return a table from the function so you can do a SELECT on it, look [here](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/Oracle/PL-SQL/collection-types/return-table-from-function/index).  But since you are calculating a single scalar value, not sure of its purpose.

Comment: I need to return a single row with the Following columns. Total - Vigentes - PorVencer - Criticos. Not just a single value

Comment: OK then look at the link I put in.

Answer (score 0):

In a package, you can create cursor which executes the query, then return a cursor %ROWTYPE value from a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE COUNT_STUFF_PKG AS
  CURSOR csrCount_stuff IS
    SELECT ((SELECT count(*)
               FROM persona
               WHERE DTYPE = 'Vendedor' AND
                     ACTIVO = 1) *
            (SELECT count(*)
               FROM TIPO_DOCUMENTO
               WHERE ENTIDAD = 'Vendedor' AND
                     ACTIVO = 1) +

            (SELECT count(*)
               FROM persona
               WHERE DTYPE = 'Peoneta' AND
               ACTIVO = 1) *
            (SELECT count(*)
               FROM TIPO_DOCUMENTO
               WHERE ENTIDAD = 'Peoneta' AND
                     ACTIVO = 1) +

            (SELECT count(*)
               FROM VEHICULO
               WHERE ACTIVO = 1) *
            (SELECT count(*)
               FROM TIPO_DOCUMENTO
               WHERE ENTIDAD = 'Vehiculo' AND
                     ACTIVO = 1 )) AS total, 

           --Vigentes
           ((SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM DOC_PERS
               WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA >  SYSDATE +30 AND
                     ACTIVO = 1) +
            (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM DOC_VEH
               WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA > SYSDATE +30 AND
                     ACTIVO = 1))AS Vigentes,

           --PorVencer
           ((SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM DOC_PERS
               WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA < SYSDATE +30 AND
                     FECHA_VIGENCIA > SYSDATE + 15 AND
                     ACTIVO = 1) +
            (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM DOC_VEH
               WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA < SYSDATE +30 AND
                     FECHA_VIGENCIA > SYSDATE +15 AND
                     ACTIVO = 1)) AS PorVencer,

           --Criticos
           ((SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM DOC_PERS
               WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA < SYSDATE +15 AND
                     FECHA_VIGENCIA > SYSDATE  AND
                     ACTIVO = 1) +
            (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM DOC_VEH
               WHERE FECHA_VIGENCIA < SYSDATE +15 AND
                     FECHA_VIGENCIA > SYSDATE AND
                     ACTIVO = 1)) AS Criticos
    FROM DUAL;

  FUNCTION COMPUTE_STUFF
    RETURN COUNT_STUFF_PKG.csrCount_stuff%ROWTYPE
END COUNT_STUFF_PKG;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY COUNT_STUFF_PKG AS
  FUNCTION COMPUTE_STUFF
    RETURN COUNT_STUFF_PKG.csrCount_stuff%ROWTYPE
  IS
    rowCount_stuff  COUNT_STUFF_PKG.csrCount_stuff%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
    OPEN csrCount_stuff;

    FETCH csrCount_stuff
      INTO rowCount_stuff;

    CLOSE csrCount_stuff;

    RETURN rowCount_stuff;
  END COMPUTE_STUFF;
END COUNT_STUFF_PKG;
```